# Taylor series expansion of $ f(x)=e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, analyticity

How to find Taylor series expansion of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$
What I'm stuck at is proving that the error $$R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$ of the expansion tends to zero.

Comment: I think the best way to find it is to start with the series for $e^x$ and plug in $-x^2$ for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f^{(n+1)}(x)=H_{n+1}(x)e^{-x^2}\ ,
$$
where $H_n(x)$ is the $n$-th Hermite polynomial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function . So it is a polynomial of degree $n+1$. The remainder then
$$
R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}\sim (cx)^{n+1}e^{-c^2}/(n+1)!\to 0\ ,
$$
as factorials grow faster than exponentials.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do in such cases is to write first the series of $\textrm e ^x$ and then replace $x$ by $-x^2$. This means that in

$$\textrm e ^x = \sum _{n=0} ^\infty \frac {x^n} {n!}$$

you plug $-x^2$, getting

$$\textrm e ^{-x^2} = \sum _{n=0} ^\infty (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {n!} .$$

Comment: I'm using Taylor's theorem $f(x)=P_n(x) + R_n(x)$, what I want to prove is that $R_n(x)$ (error) is zero as n tends to infinity.

Comment: @wilbur: In this case you are not asking about the Taylor series (because a series has no remainder), but about the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$.